# Swift: Ask user to input the text file name after each stop button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I created a stop button that can collect data, which will be saved to the defined path after clicking the stop button. However, if I want to continue collecting after clicking the stop button, the data will be added to the original text file. (This makes senses as I only know how to define one path)

My question is: **Would it be possible to ask the user and input a new file name and save as a new text file after each stop so that the data is not added to the original file?**

Below is what I have for one defined path and stacking up the data:

```
    @IBAction func stopbuttonTapped(_ btn: UIButton) {
        do {
            let username:String = user_name.text!
            fpsTimer.invalidate() //turn off the timer
            let capdata = captureData.map{$0.verticesFormatted}.joined(separator:"") //convert capture data to string
            let dir: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last! as URL
            let url = dir.appendingPathComponent("testing.txt") //name the file
            try capdata.appendLineToURL(fileURL: url as URL)
            let result = try String(contentsOf: url as URL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        }
        catch {
            print("Could not write to file")
        }
}
```

And the extension I use for string and data:

```
 extension String {
   func appendLineToURL(fileURL: URL) throws {
        try (self).appendToURL(fileURL: fileURL)
    }

    func appendToURL(fileURL: URL) throws {
        let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        try data.append(fileURL: fileURL)
    }
    func trim() -> String
      {
       return self.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
      }
}
extension Data {
    func append(fileURL: URL) throws {
        if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileURL.path) {
            defer {
                fileHandle.closeFile()
            }
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.write(self)
        }
        else {
            try write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to set a default file name (maybe texting.txt) and then popped up a user input for saving the text file? (That's where I am not too sure how to integrate to what I already have). I thank you so much for your time and suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate unique names.

For example:

```
let url = dir.appendingPathComponent("testing-\(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate).txt")
```

or

```
let url = dir.appendingPathComponent("testing-\(UUID().uuidString).txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It outputs a separated file after each click! For the file name, I got the time number that I don't really understand, its 613509736.89 like so. It is possible to get the current time? I tried Date().timeIntervalSinceNow and still gave me some number that I don't really understand

Comment: It’s the number of seconds since the reference date. You can turn it back into a date with the Date init that reverses it. You could also format to make it readable: https://medium.com/@lugearma/converting-date-string-to-date-type-with-swift-8b6b2f07d50